# Unparseable Json Response

Tags: php, actions-on-google, google-home

Since i am not getting an accessToken with the simulator Request I did the above as said in 
https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/account-linking#json
*Request the signin helper*

```
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
   $askToken = array (
  'conversationToken' => '{"state":null,"data":{}}',
  'expectUserResponse' => true,
  'expectedInputs' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'inputPrompt' => 
      array (
        'initialPrompts' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'textToSpeech' => 'MY AUTHENTICATION END POINT URL',
          ),
        ),
        'noInputPrompts' => 
        array (
        ),
      ),
      'possibleIntents' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'intent' => 'actions.intent.SIGN_IN',
          'inputValueData' => 
          array (
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
echo json_encode($askToken);


    exit();
```

I get an error

## Simulator Response

```
"

sharedDebugInfo": [
            {
                "name": "ResponseValidation",
                "subDebugEntry": [
                    {
                        "name": "UnparseableJsonResponse",
                        "debugInfo": "API Version 2: Failed to parse JSON response string with 'INVALID_ARGUMENT' error: \"expected_inputs[0].possible_intents[0]: Proto field is not repeating, cannot start list.\"."
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "visualResponse": {}
}
```

Error

API Version 2: Failed to parse JSON response string with 'INVALID_ARGUMENT' error: \"expected_inputs[0].possible_intents[0]: Proto field is not repeating, cannot start list.\"."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters - that is a pretty good error message from the Simulator. It tells you the exact path in the JSON where there is an error, so one can use the documentation for [the webhook response](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppResponse) to track down why your JSON might not look like the expected JSON.

In this case, the value for `inputValueData` must be a JSON object, not a JSON array. By default PHP's `json_encode()` function assumes that empty PHP arrays are empty JSON arrays (and this is a correct assumption for the `noInputPrompts` property).

You need to force it to be an object. You **can't** use the JSON_FORCE_OBJECT setting, because then `noInputPrompts` would change to an object, which is also wrong.

You need to cast the array to an object using syntax such as

```
(object)array()
```

So your code would look something like

```
$askToken = array (
  'conversationToken' => '{"state":null,"data":{}}',
  'expectUserResponse' => true,
  'expectedInputs' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'inputPrompt' => 
      array (
        'initialPrompts' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'textToSpeech' => 'MY AUTHENTICATION END POINT URL',
          ),
        ),
        'noInputPrompts' => 
        array (
        ),
      ),
      'possibleIntents' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'intent' => 'actions.intent.SIGN_IN',
          'inputValueData' => 
          (object)array (
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
echo json_encode($askToken);
```

Comment: After i did it i just get 'Sorry, I didn't get any response.'

Comment: In the docs, https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/account-linking#json they have somthing called PLACEHOLDER_FOR_SIGN_IN. Is it supposed to be my authentication end point url or?